# Unable to get gdal_polygonize function to work in R

Tags: raster, gdal, r, polygonize

I know there have been previous questions with respect to the same. I have been trying to polygonize a raster using modified code from John Baumgartner.

Link : https://gist.github.com/johnbaums/26e8091f082f2b3dd279

I have installed Python 2.7 as well as installed the Anacondas framework for writing code. In addition, I installed the latest version of OSGeo4w for Windows, but I keep getting this error.

```
> p <- polygonizer(r)
  Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv 
   = use_iconv,  : 
     Cannot open data source
      In addition: Warning message:
     running command '"python" "C:\Users\vr235\DOWNLO~1\gdal222\GDAL-2~1.2\swig\python\scripts\GDAL_P~2.PY" 
     "C:\Users\vr235\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeGRpnN\file33e8d1c7717.tif" -q  -f "ESRI Shapefile" 
      "C:\Users\vr235\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeGRpnN\file33e825205ec7.shp"' had status 127
```

Here, r is the raster I would like to polygonize. I am using this code as rastertoPolygons takes forever to finish running.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that `"C:\Users\vr235\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeGRpnN\file33e8d1c7717.tif"` exists? Maybe it has .grd extension

Comment: status 127 is usually a "command not found" problem. Maybe you could try with simpler installation paths;

Comment: @radouxju Any suggestions on ways to do the same? I am unsure as to how to do the same.

Comment: @aldo_tapia I am unsure as to what it is referring to? I don't think there is a .tif at that location.

Comment: @VijayRamesh if there isn't .tif, the shell command is incorrect